# Mix google App script with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-forms

I am just new to google app script and i have created a new google form using the following code in code.gs file:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
  form.addTextItem()
      .setTitle('Model #')
}
```

The code worked fine and now I have a google form with a text question (Model #). I am just wondering if it is possible to mix a HTML file with my code.gs file so that I could modify the color/font of the text "Model #" using the codes in the HTML file. I guess I need to include another function in the code.gs to  "call" my codes in the html file? 
thx!

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation to change the color of a text item.  [Apps Script Documentation - text item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#methods)